# Error while adding link to the content body - Web.config registration missing

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, content-management

We are facing a issue while adding a link to the content body and creating a new item in our application using content editor.

Exception thrown:

> Web.config registration missing!
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1590.0

Screenshot
[image: Error Message]

We are using Sitecore 8.2 initial release

[image]

Comment: Can you add some clarify to your question around how you add link to content body (screenshots are best)?

Comment: @PeterProchazka: while creating the New Item as per screenshot and adding the link, we get the message as per screenshot

Comment: Yes, it is there but commented. I tried un-comment and checking but same issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that following [this security bulletin](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/978654) caused this issue. To get rid from vulnerability someone deleted Telerik handlers from web.config for CM servers. But Telerik handlers are required on CM server for all Telerik controls features, they could be removed only on CD.

You should do next steps for Sitecore 8.2:

1. Download the ZIP archive [containing the hotfix](https://dl.sitecore.net/hotfix/Sitecore%20CMS%208.1-8.2%20Security%20Hotfix%20170504.zip)
2. Back up the following files in your Sitecore website folder: \bin\Telerik.Web.UI.dll, \bin\Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll, \bin\Telerik.Web.UI.xml, \sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\RTEfixes.js
3. Extract the contents of the archive to the Sitecore website folder.
4. Open the web.config file within your Sitecore website root folder.
5. Add the following lines within the `<appSettings>` node:

[image]

6. Replace the placeholder text "YOUR_ENCRYPTION_KEY_HERE" with a string of characters that will be used to secure the capabilities of Telerik controls. The string should be a set of random characters and numbers, up to a length of 256 characters. We recommend a minimum of 32 characters to be used.
7. Under the  node of the  section in the web.config file, add the following configuration:
   [image]
8. Save and close the web.config file.
9. Clear the browser cache.
10. If you have a `<machineKey>` node under the  section in the web.config file, [generate a new Machine Key](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey).

For more detail about issue and fixes for other Sitecore versions, please review [original article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/978654).

Comment: HI Anton, I tried the option provided but without any luck. As per the original Article, I had commented/removed the three references but when when I removed the third reference, I was not able to open up the text editor in Sitecore. I added the third reference again and was able to open the text editor but the original issue as screenshot is not resolved. when clicked "OK" on screenshot got another error as per another screenshot added to the original question.,

Comment: @PushpendraVats
you should remove on CD server. On CM server it should be present, but be properly configured.

Comment: I had removed from CD servers and are there on CM servers but issue persist.

Comment: @PushpendraVats Can you try using developer tools in browser look on network request that is sent after attempt to add a link to the content body?